# Best way to count words in a string on SQL impala/Hive

Tags: sql, hive, count, impala

I need to count words in a string, with SQL Impala/Hive. What is the best way?
In Oracle I use regexp_count() function, like the example below:

```
SELECT regexp_count('1aa 2bb 3cc', '\s*[a-z]+\s*'); -- result: 3
```

In impala/hive we can't use the above function. Which is the best way to achieve this goal?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you simply use this formula - count of words = count of spaces +1.

so calculate total length and then length of all spaces removed or replaced by empty string. Minus first from second and you will get number of spaces.
Add 1 to it.

```
select length('1aa 2bb 3cc') - length(replace('1aa 2bb 3cc',' ',''))+1
```

Comment: Wow!! @Koushik Roy This is a good approach. If there's any better than this, I'm satisfied.

Comment: simple, and faster than regex. glad you like it...

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can do it with **split** and **size** function which returns the length of the split array.

```sql
SELECT size(split('1aa 2bb 3cc', ' ')); -- result: 3
```

Comment: Most appreciated @Alex. Your solution seems rather practical and simple, but There's no split or size functions in Impala/Hive. Can you translate your solution, please?

Comment: @LEOPOLDO, I'm not familiar with Impala but above query has been tested on Hive.
kindly check **size()** and **split()** function here - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+udf

Comment: Sorry @Alex. You're alright. That worked fine in HIVE. I thank you very much. The main reason for me to maintain the Koushik Roy solution, is for the compatibility reasons for both impala / Hive motors. But this one is more effectively simple. Tahnk you very much.